# Multiple imputation in SPSS: merge datasets?

Tags: spss, dataset, multiple-imputation

I have two sets of data, measured from the same persons. The variables in the two sets are very different. There are some extreme values (occurring at random) in both sets I would like to handle using multiple imputation. I would like to do this using SPSS, which I believe uses some kind of Markov-chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) method for the imputation.

Now, the problem I have is this: should I do the imputation for the two sets separately or should I merge them into one big dataset and then do the multiple imputation for the merged dataset?

Comment: I am not sure that multiple imputation (MI) is the method you need. MI is usually used only for handling **missing data**. In your case, it seems to me that you need to handle **outliers**. Please see [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Working_with_outliers) as a starting point.

Comment: The outliers were defined as points having z-score larger than six. I am not sure if I should consider them as known values, since they are just some huge errors. I even have one variable that has it usual range between 10-100, and one point that has value near half million.

Comment: I should maybe add that the sample size is N=100, there are about 50 variables in each set.

Comment: An outlier is not the same as a missing value. The presence of specific unusual values and ranges might point you to some pattern and/or issues with data source and/or data collection. I still think that you have to treat outliers as such instead of as missing values. But that's just my two cents.

Comment: Why not? A very extreme value does not contain any useful information. Also some sources consider imputation as one possible way to deal with outliers. Some even say it is better than e.g. deleting observations.

Comment: I never suggested deleting observations. Quite the opposite - one of my points was to consider investigating the underlying reasons for having extreme outliers, which may reveal some potential issues. So, in this sense, extreme values might contain some useful information. As for using MI to handle outliers, I haven't heard about this approach and am curious to take a look at sources you're talking about.